# Arris DG860A and ASUS RT-AC66U to cover two floors

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I have an Arris DG860A modem from my ISP with built in four port switch and wireless N. I also have my own ASUS RT-AC66U wireless router. How can I configure both of them to get the best wireless coverage on both floors of my house. Currently the Arris is just acting as a modem, it's sitting on the top floor and the ASUS router is wired to it, but the wireless coverage is not good enough at some spots on the first floor so i would like to leverage the wireless capabilities of the Arris as well to get better coverage.

How should i configure both devices to achieve this kind of coverage?

I can move the ASUS to the ground floor if i need to.

I have the admin credentials for the Arris and can make config changes.

Comment: There's no way that someone on the internet can answer this unless they physically go to your house and test it.

Comment: @Moses You could give a general answer telling the OP how to test it and what configuration tweaks could be made.

Comment: @slhck True, point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the asus router in AP mode and connect the two devices together. I recommend using different SSIDs since some devices will always connect to the first router they have seen with a SSID. It'll also set your 'wan' port to being a lan port, so you can plug in ethernet to any port.

Alternatively, if you want to have different subnets you can leave the asus router in router mode, set them to separate subnets , and connect from a lan port to lan port.

Asus's documentation talks about [AP mode](http://support.asus.com/Search/KDetail.aspx?no=28C95A86-C1D7-F359-7B45-F8F6B966E8BA&t=2) here.

I'd also warn that there's some reports of the arris having issues with wireless - see [this](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/problems-with-wireless-connection-arris-dg860a-698625.html) and [this](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r27274883-TWC-Does-anyone-else-have-an-Arris-DG860a-modem-). If you want to get things *perfect* and get an idea of how your connection really is like, and to pick the perfect channel, grab a android tablet (it runs on phones too, but the extra real-estate is useful), load up [inssider](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) and walk around when you're experimenting with specific locations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as placement of your modem and router, I'd suggest checking this article out: http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessproducts/qt/locate_aprouter.htm

For configuration, set your wifi to use the least busy wifi channel. If you have a lot of wireless networks in your area, this can make a big difference. Also try to use non-overlapping channels between your two devices (channels 1,6,or 11).

If you want your two devices to broadcast the same wifi SSID (name), you should configure your ASUS to NOT provide DHCP (make your Arris provide DHCP for the entire network, or vice versa). If you do this, you should be able to roam the building without having to worry about having to switch wifi networks if you loose signal. It should be noted though, when initially connecting to your wifi network, the device will usually decide to connect to the strongest signal. However, it isn't guaranteed that the devices switches to the other access point if/when the signal gets stronger. Most of the time, the device will stay connected to the initial access point as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest using a cereal box, some cellophane-type tape and heavy duty aluminum foil to redirect signal from where you don't need it, to where you do need it. http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-WIFI-Antenna-Reception-Booster provides illustrated instruction.